# How to annotate a chart at a specific data point

Tags: javascript, protovis

Using Protovis, I generate a candlestick chart similar to this: http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/candlestick-full.html. I need to annotate the chart for a specific candlestick. For instance, I could draw triangle at the position of the 12:00 candlestick. How do I find the position (left and bottom) of that specific candlestick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the standard protovis approach to this is to make the annotation mark a child mark of the data point you're interested in, then set its `visible` property to only display for the data point you're interested in. For the candlestick example, it might look like this:

```
// the thin line of the candlestick
var candlestick = vis.add(pv.Rule)
    .data(vix)
    .left(function(d) x(d.date))
    .bottom(function(d) y(Math.min(d.high, d.low)))
    .height(function(d) Math.abs(y(d.high) - y(d.low)))
    .strokeStyle(function(d) d.open < d.close ? "#ae1325" : "#06982d");

// the thick line of the candlestick
candlestick.add(pv.Rule)
    .bottom(function(d) y(Math.min(d.open, d.close)))
    .height(function(d) Math.abs(y(d.open) - y(d.close)))
    .lineWidth(10);

// the annotation mark
candlestick.add(pv.Dot)
    .size(40)
    .shape("triangle")
    .left(function() {
        // candlestick here refers to the parent instance
        return candlestick.left()
    })
    .top(function() {
        // candlestick here refers to the parent instance
        // this is 10px from the top of the candlestick
        return h - candlestick.bottom() - candlestick.height() - 10;
    })
    .visible(function(d) {
        // only show the mark for the data we care about - here, June 12
        // (month is 0-based)
        return d.date.getUTCMonth() == 5 && d.date.getUTCDate() == 12;
    });
```

The other option, if you need to get the data outside of the protovis context (e.g. you want to show a `div` there with HTML text) would be to grab the data as it's being defined (e.g. in the `bottom` and `height` property functions of the `candlestick` definition) and store it in a global variable. This is pretty ugly, though.